# android action bar styling

Tags: java, android

I have this action bar, I'm trying to change the color of the  menu icon at the right of the bar (its actual color is dark gray) to white. I wrote the following in styles.xml :

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

The text color changed but the color of the menu icon stills the same, any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this great tool: [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: Actually it's a great tool but it didn't answer my question, I want to change precisely the color of the menu icon, thank you